# Netflix Conductor WorkflowStatusListener

Tags: microservices, extend, orchestration, conductor

I'm using Netflix Conductor over Rest API. I'm able to create a workflow and run it but I would like to know how to use the workflowStatusListener feature.

I'm running Conductor on my localhost with Docker and I saw that the server is a simple jar, possibly a SpringBoot app. So, how to pass my on jar with my Listener or Simple Tasks in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to deploy it using the Docker image.

I copied the folder /app from my docker container, changed the startup.sh script and mounted my local folder.

I copied my jar into /app/libs

`java -cp libs/*.jar com.netflix.conductor.bootstrap.Main $config_file $log4j_file`

Comment: One thing to add: once your have define your WorkflowStatusListener implementation, and module binding, you also needed to config the property `conductor.additional.modules=<your-module>`